# Correctly dismissing progress dialog

Tags: android, android-activity, progressdialog, android-lifecycle

I have a progress dialog that I need to dismiss and then finish the app.
The way I'm doing it is like this:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                            .setMessage("There has been a problem.")
                            .setPositiveButton("OK",
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(
                                                DialogInterface dialog,
                                                int which) {
                                            dialog.dismiss();
                                            finish();
                                        }
                                    }).show();
```

Nevertheless, I always get the famous error:

```
Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.app.LocalActivityManager$LocalActivityRecord@48189240 is not valid; is your activity running?
05-23 16:56:44.573: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2494):     at android.view.ViewRoot.setView(ViewRoot.java:505)
05-23 16:56:44.573: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2494):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:200)
05-23 16:56:44.573: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2494):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:114)
05-23 16:56:44.573: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2494):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
05-23 16:56:44.573: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2494):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
05-23 16:56:44.573: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2494):     at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:107)
05-23 16:56:44.573: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2494):     at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:90)
05-23 16:56:44.573: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2494):     at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:85)
```

How could I dismiss it without problems? am I doing it right?

Thanks a lot in advance.

EDIT: I can get to show it perfectly, and even when dismissing it, the user doesn't see anything wrong, but in my LogCat I can see that nasty error.

Comment: Are you able display it initially..?

Comment: seems like you are creating your dialog while your activity is not active/visible. you can't use your activity as a context for your dialog if it is not going to be there when the dialog shows

Comment: @ngesh I edited my question to answer to you

Comment: I tested this code in Android 2.3.4 and 4.1 and it worked - dialog dismissed and activity finished. Perhaps the problem is coming from somewhere else?

Comment: Once the activity goes to paused state this error will happen. So I think the issue is happening while showing the dialog and would like to know when you are showing the dialog

Comment: Can you just tell me when you are getting above exception ? While displaying the dialog or while dismissing the dialog ? If it is while dismissing the dialog, just check whether dialog is displaying or not. 'if(progressDialog.isShowing()){
  progressDialog.dismiss();
       }' If it is while displaying the dialog, verify "MainActivity" you are using to show dialog is in the foreground. If not you will get this issue.

Comment: @android.fryo it happens when dismissing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this, though it should work. However, as an alternate, you may call `finish()` in your dialog's `onClick` and in your activity's `onStop` call `dialog.dismiss()`.

Calling dismiss in onStop will avoid the *window leak* warning message.

Comment: this means that my dialog needs to be a class variable, since I need to access to it (in order to dismiss it) in the onStop method, doesn't it?